# Graph API incorrectly returning empty array

Tags: facebook, response

I'm trying to run a simple query on the graph api. I just want to pull back the id of a user based on the email address they use to login to facebook.

I am using the following query:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=facebook.xxx@xxx.xid.au&type=user&access_token=AAADxxxxT64Q8BADcpCdWBojPXPLbZBsSjzj8LPUPhyYJMGWaRuZAP56wIR4BaiUZAaPZA22Ex2y7bgBQHTxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

and am getting the following in response (no errors, no data)

```
{
   "data": [

   ]
}
```

I know the email address is valid - it is my own. This query had worked fine in the past. Any tips on where I should look to for debugging?

Comment: I've modified my code so that I no longer use the search api. Not really an answer, but I figured I would mark this as 'solved' to revert attention to the more immediate problems of other's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=facebook.xxx@xxx.xid.au&type=user

Due to privacy concerns searching by email address has been disabled.

However, if you have a user who has granted you `email` permissions, you can get their email address, however you are limited as to what you can use that email address for.

**EDIT**

It was filed as a bug (https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/292220680814266) and now is resolved.

Looks like Facebook has caved in to peer pressure and is now allowing this search to happen again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have no permission to access user's data.
see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/ for more details

Comment: Thanks for the reply Suj. It doesn't make sense that this would be the problem. I am just searching to see whether the user exists, I'm not trying to read any data about them.